# Check if user is followed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I've created a follow feature in my rails/angular app. In my template I have this,

```
%ul{"ng-repeat" => "user in users"}
  %li
    name: {{ user.name }}
    %a{"ng-click" => "followUser(user)"} Follow user.
```

Which calls for this function,

```
$scope.followUser = function (user) {
  $scope.user = user
  console.log ($scope.user)

  followUser.create({
    followed_id:   $scope.user.id
  })

  Notification.success($scope.user.name + ' is toegevoegd als vriend.');
}
```

Which calls for this service,

```
app.factory('followUser', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    create: function(user) {
      return $http.post('/relationships.json', user);
    }
  };
}])
```

And then creates the relationship here,

```
def create
  @relationship = current_user.active_relationships.build(:followed_id => params[:followed_id])
  if @relationship.save
    redirect_to root_url
  else

  end
end
```

This is the user model,

```
has_many :active_relationships,  class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   foreign_key: "follower_id",
                                   dependent:   :destroy

has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                 foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                 dependent:   :destroy

has_many :following, through: :active_relationships,  source: :followed
has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower
```

And the relationship model,

```
belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
```

I want to check if the user in user is already being followed. If so the template should display the unfollow function. So I was thinking something like this,

```
%ul{"ng-repeat" => "user in users"}
  %li{"ng-if" => "user.followed == false "}
    name: {{ user.name }}
    %a{"ng-click" => "followUser(user)"} Follow user.
  %li{"ng-if" => "user.followed == true "}
    name: {{ user.name }}
    %a{"ng-click" => "followUser(user)"} Unfollow user.
```

So I want to set a value called `followed` to true or false when a user is followed. So I can check that value through a ng-if. But I don't think it's possible to set  that value for each different user.

Bob can follow Joe, setting the `followed` value to true. But this would mean that for every user Joe is now followed. So how do I set the `followed` value only for Bob.

Comment: What is the specific problem or question?

Comment: Sorry the question got rather large. I want to set the value of followed to true or false for each different user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an array of all `followed_id`'s in the `active_relationships` of your current user for example if it is `$scope.currentUser`.

For example your `$scope.currentUser.activeRelationships` should return something like `[2, 3, 4]` which are ids for users followed.

Create a method to check of the user is followed by the currentUser.

```
$scope.followed = function (user) {
  $scope.user = user
  if ($scope.currentUser.activeRelationships.indexOf($scope.user.id) > -1 {
     return true;
  }
 else {
   return false;
 }
}
```

Edit your service to add a `destroy` call

```
app.factory('followUser', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    create: function(user) {
      return $http.post('/relationships.json', user);
    },
    destroy: function(user) {
      return $http.delete('/relationships.json', user);
    }
  };
}])
```

Add your `unfollowUser` method to

```
$scope.unfollowUser = function (user) {
  $scope.user = user
  console.log ($scope.user)
  followUser.destroy({
    followed_id:   $scope.user.id
  })

  Notification.success($scope.user.name + ' werd verwijderd uit vrienden.');
}
```

Create a `destroy` method on your API controller.

```
def destroy
  if current_user.active_relationships.where(:followed_id => params[:followed_id]).destroy_all
    redirect_to root_url
end
```

If a user has a large number of relationships so just try to divide the data according to the view of the users you have. For example if you load users with ids 1 through 10 and your current user follows users with ids 1 and 2 then your `$scope.currentUser.activeRelationships` should include only `[1, 2]`. You should update it accordingly with your request to fetch more users from your server. Like to following

**users_controller.rb**

```
def index
   users = User.page(params[:page])
   followed_by_current_user = current_user.active_relationships.where(followed_id: @users.pluck(:id)).pluck(:followed_id)
   render json: {users: @users, followed: followed_by_current_user}
end
```

And then update your `$scope.currentUser.activeRelationships` array with the data from this method.

This last step is for scalability and space complexity reasons.

Good luck!